# Shell script for stopping the tomcat

Tags: linux, tomcat, centos7, tomcat9

How to write the shell script for to stop the tomcat.

```
tomcat version -  tomcat9
  environment  -  Linux
   OS          -  centos7
```

Comment: How did you start it?

Comment: i have started usind ./catalina.sh run. I need to write the shutdown script

Answer (score 0):

The scripts located in the Tomcat directory are the most barebones ways of starting the server.
To stop the Tomcat server change active directory to the tomcat root and execute

```
./catalina.sh stop
```

---

I recommend reading this article by O'Reilly to better understand how tomcat works:
[Starting, Stopping, and Restarting Tomcat](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/tomcat-the-definitive/9780596101060/ch01s02.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create basic shell script and add one of the following commands mentioned below. If need to automate that can be done by `CronScheduler` built in Linux tool.

There are two ways this can be done in `Linux` and `Windows`.

**Linux:**

```
./catalina.sh stop
```

Passing "stop" argument for catalina.sh --> stops the **Tomcat in the background**. Since in background no issues closing down the terminal. The logs need to be viewed as below: `tail -f $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out`

```
./shutdown.sh
```

The last way is firing the shutdown.sh to stop your Tomcat server. If you Vi the script you can see it calls **catalina.sh script passing stop as the argument**. This will be running in background as well.

**Windows:**

```
shutdown.bat // stop tomcat server
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a file and write the following lines of code:

```
#!/bin/bash
systemctl stop tomcat
```

execute the bash script: bash fileName.sh

Comment: Then try starting it and stopping it using the following commands in the bash script:
./catalina.sh start
./catalina.sh stop